# Similar to % in an equal operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We know that in `LIKE` operator there is `%` value to represent all values is valid, but is there exist similar value in `equal(=)` operator?

Comment: why you need so, you can use like for wildcards and = for equality

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do, perhaps with an example? I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @Gabe - My guess is optional search parameters and when not supplied they want to match all rows.

Comment: You're right @MartinSmith, did you have better solution when we code it via stored procedure?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis - Everything you wanted to know about the topic. [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

```
WHERE col1 LIKE '%'
```

matches all `NOT NULL` values of `col1` not all rows.

To achieve the exact same semantics with `=` you could just do

```
WHERE col1 = col1
```

but it would be best just to omit that meaningless expression from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: will `WHERE col1 = col1` significantly decrease performance?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis - It could do. From a quick test here the presence of the condition means SQL Server doesn't use the narrower index on `col2` in this case beacause of the condition `CREATE TABLE T (col2 int not null primary key nonclustered, col1 int not null);SELECT col2 FROM T where col1 = col1`

Comment: so, as long as there are no null values, the solution is still ok, right?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis - It means you may well get  sub optimal plans. Dynamically generated SQL may well be a better option or see the [article I linked earlier](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) that discusses using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: BTW thanks for [this useful article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). I agree it's better to keep the query in a variable and execute It at end of dynamic criteria statement.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `LIKE` is that it supports wildcards.

Equals means exactly that – **equal**, not like.

Comment: Almost want to vote this down because it's so smart.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: I'm trying to get people who ask this kind of question to **think** for themselves, instead of asking us to do all of their thinking for them.

Comment: -1 this doesn't answer the question. The implication I guess is supposed to be "no" but actually it is entirely possible to achieve the same effect as `LIKE %` with `=`

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you happened to guess exactly what the OP wanted to know (though it wasn't necessarily obvious from his wording IMO) and this answer was posted before you helped clarify the OP's underlying concern.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is not an operator but a placeholder for "any arbitrary string".

No. That's what `LIKE` is for. You may use string functions like `instring(...)` but that's not a `placeholder`